# Asp .Net MVC WatiN failing assert

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, automated-tests, watin

So I just got a hold of WatiN and wanted to do some automated acceptance tests.
I've got resharper, as well as Nunit and WatiN using NuGet manager. Changed the reference Interop.SHDocVw property of Embed Interop to false so everything works fine, the browser shows up, writes text in a box(kinda fast so I only see the end result and no the typing which I don't know if it's possible to slow it down), clicks a button, etc.. Well... fine until I add an Assert in the end of my Test. It fails.
It kinda looks like the browser is closing before the test finishes. I've used the WaitForComplete() method but it looks like it doesn't do anything. Is there a way to fix that?

```
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using WatiN.Core;

namespace Testy
{
    [TestFixture]
    [Apartment(ApartmentState.STA)]
    public class UnitTest2
    {
        [Test]
        public void SearchForWatiNOnGoogle()
        {
            using (var browser = new IE("google.com"))
            {
                browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
                browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();
                Assert.IsTrue(browser.ContainsText("WatiN"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what I tried but with no better results.

```
[Test]
        public void SearchForWatiNOnGoogle()
        {
            using (var browser = new IE("google.com"))
            {
                browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
                browser.WaitForComplete(4000);
                browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();
                browser.WaitForComplete(4000);
                Assert.IsTrue(browser.ContainsText("WatiN"));
                browser.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the autoclose to false ie

```
browser.AutoClose = false;
```

however - that project hasn't been active in years. What about the functionality built right into Visual Studio for this for [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx)?